# Where to add css and js files in ember-cli app?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

In rails,

js files are located under

```
app/assets/javascripts
```

Similarly where to add js and css files in ember-cli app ?

Answer (score 7):

`app/styles/` should contain your stylesheets:

```
Contains your stylesheets, whether SASS, LESS, Stylus, Compass, or plain CSS
(though only one type is allowed, see Asset Compilation).
These are all compiled into <app-name>.css
```

If you need external JavaScript libraries, you should manage them in dependency sections of `package.json` and `bower.json`. You may have to include the assets manually in the build. This could be done by `app.import()` in `ember-cli-build.js` or by using [ember-auto-import](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import). Have a look in the [User Guide](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/advanced-use/asset-compilation/) for more details.

User Guide also contains a section about [folder layout](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#folder-layout) in ember-cli.