# Ember css dosen't work + How to create two stylsheets

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js

I'm new to ember and I try bulid some application
So my first question was how to add css , I google it and I found this answer [Where to add css and js files in ember-cli app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481541/where-to-add-css-and-js-files-in-ember-cli-app)
So what I did is to create `header.css` file in `app\styles`
The CSS content is:

```
header {
     background-color: #0c2635;
     color: #a2a2a2;
     padding:30px;
 }
 header h1 {
     text-align:center;
     font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
     font-size:60px;
 }
 nav#navbar {
     background-color:#dcdcdc;
     margin-bottom:25px;
 }
 nav#navbar ul {
     list-style-type: none;
 }
 nav#navbar ul li {
     display:inline-block;
 }
```

My `application.hbs` contain this HTML:

```
<header>
<h1>DrawYourGIF</h1>
</header>
<nav id="navbar">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            צפה בכל הגיפים
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="pull-end">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            הרשמה
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="pull-end">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            התחברות
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

But the result that I get is that:

[image: result]

Nothing is work

Why is that? How can I make its work?

2)
I want to bulid site for two languages

How can I make one css that will be used once when I need `rtl` and once that I need `ltr`?

Comment: Change your `css` file into `scss` and import it into `app.scss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app.css, you can import multiple css.

@import 'header.css';

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question